# Get specific value from sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Let's take the following table as an example:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

I used a sap.ui.table.Table for this (single choice).
What I want now is to get the value of Column2 of the selected row from the table.

I already managed to get the index of the selected row  with the following code:

`MyTable.getSelectedIndex();`

Now I just need to get the value of Column2 of the row with this index, but I don't know how.

Comment: Is there a model (json or odata) bound to your table? You can consider leveraging it rather than inferring the value from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with  `MyTable.getRows()[MyTable.getSelectedIndex()].getCells()` you can get all cells of your row.
IF column2 is ALWAYS the 2nd row, you can just use `MyTable.getRows()[MyTable.getSelectedIndex()].getCells()[1]`
If not you need to loop over the cells and select the one you need.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I think there is something missing here? Because with this code I'm receiving an object and not the value.

Comment: well you get whatever controll you have in that cell. I cant tell you what that is, aslong i dont have the code of your table. But for most controlls it should be getText or getValue. Just look up the properties of your controll in the api reference

Comment: Perfect, in my case it was getText(). Thank you!